# javascript/jquery half hour interval between 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is print times between a start and a stop time, with half hour space.

I have already implemented it, using php but I want to do it using javascript or jquery.

My php code in case it helps:

```
for($n = strtotime("09:00"), $e = strtotime("23:30"); $n <= $e; $n += 1800)  
     echo date("H:i", $n);
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple javascript for-loop? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
var day1 = new Date("2000-12-17T03:24:00");
var day2 = new Date("2000-12-17T06:22:00");

while (day1 < day2) {
   console.log(day1);
   day1.setTime(day1.getTime() + 30*60000);
}


Sun Dec 17 2000 04:24:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 
Sun Dec 17 2000 04:54:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 
Sun Dec 17 2000 05:24:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 
Sun Dec 17 2000 05:54:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 
Sun Dec 17 2000 06:24:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 
Sun Dec 17 2000 06:54:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

very hackish, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);
```